# T SQL: How get all minutes from Time type

Tags: t-sql

I have the following code and I want get all minutes from time type.

```
declare @time time
set @time = '01:30'

declare @minutes int

--select @minutes = convert time to minutes here

select @minutes -- @minutes == 90
```

Please help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The difference between `@time` & midnight;

```
set @minutes = datediff(minute, '00:00:00', @time)
```